# How to free memory of temporary string?

Tags: c, string, memory-leaks, struct, memory-management

I am playing around with my custom string library which is terrible by the way, but I am doing it for experience.

Anyways, I have some functions that allocate a block of memory for `String*` to use and it works fine.  All of the memory used is freed up when the `string_delete(string*)` function is called.
But I came up with a new way of representing `char*`s as `String*`s but I am afraid the memory I reserve for it is not being freed down the road.  Here is the function:

```
String* String_ToN(char* dest) {
  String* temp = calloc(1, sizeof (struct String));
  temp->length = strlen(dest);
  temp->buffer = (char*) malloc(temp->length + 1);
  strncpy(temp->buffer, dest, temp->length);
  return temp;
}
```

I don't like using `strdup` being it is not standard c so I'll stick with `malloc` and `strncpy`.

This works and what I use it for is something like this:

`String_GetLength(String*)` takes in a `String*` parameter, so if I put a string literal in when calling it I would get an error.

So instead I go `String_GetLength(String_ToN("hello"))` and it returns 5 like I expected it to.

But again in `String_ToN` I use `calloc` and `malloc`, how would I free this memory and still be able to use `ToN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike in C++, there is no automatic resource management in C (because there are no destructors).  You would have to do something like:

```
String *hello = String_ToN("hello");
int len = String_GetLength(hello);
String_free(hello);
```

where `String_free` does all the necessary cleanup.

Comment: is there anyway i can pass in char* to a String* parameter without having to write duplicate functions but with char* instead of String*?

Comment: @sikes: If it involves dynamic allocation of resources, then no.

Comment: @sikesusmc Not without some advanced fiddling around with the structure of String to make it look like a char[]. But you could only use char* functions where you don't need the rest of the String members anyway, so you could write your functions as char* functions, i.e. Chars_GetLength(char*), and implement your String functions by just calling those, i.e. String_GetLength(String *s){ return Chars_GetLength(s->buffer); }

Answer (score 1):

You need a function to delete or release your `String`-s, perhaps

```
void String_delete(String *s) {
  if (!s) return;
  free (s->buffer);
  // you might want memset(s, 0, sizeof(*s)); to catch more bugs
  free (s);
}
```

You might want to zero (as in the commented code) the memory before `free`-ing it. It might help catching dangling pointers bugs. But you could use tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to catch them. Alternatively, using the [Boehm's garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) is extremely useful: you can use `GC_malloc` instead of `malloc` (etc...) and don't bother calling `free` or `GC_free`. You'll find out by experience that releasing memory becomes a major issue in big programming projects (and no, [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) idiom is not a silver bullet).

Comment: What is the *point* of `s->length = 0` when you're freeing `s` in the very next line?

Comment: It could practically help catching some dangling pointers bugs... But I agree that in principle it is useless....

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Oli Charlesworth, you must create temporaty object. However, you could also add a flag

```
int dispose;
```

to your String structure and then set it while passing to some function. Then every function that get's your String must check this flag and if set, free the String structure. The code might look like this:

```
Process_String(String_ToN("Hello", 1));
```

then

```
Process_String(String *str) {
    /* do smth with str */
    if(str->dispose)
        String_Delete(srt);
}
```

I agree that this design is more error prone and not how the things get normally done. So consider it just as educational example, no more, no less.

Comment: You **could** do this, but it's inadvisable.  It's very easy to make a mistake, and it puts the responsibility for cleanup in the wrong place.

Comment: but i dont create a new object that is visible outside of the source of string because String_ToN is created within the function.

would free(String_ToN) work?

Comment: @sikes usmc: Yes, it will work. What you pass is the pointer to the newly allocated object. This design however is not standard and should not be used for everything else as an educational example. Use a temporary object as it was suggested by Oli Charlesworth.